# Using a for loop in Javascript to enter an object into HTML div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use a for-loop to reiterate over the object material and enter the material into a div on my html. Right now I have the code set to accept an array, but I'd like to use an object instead.

```
var animals = [
  {
    name:'Aye Aye',
    description: 'blue',
    img: 'http://cdnimg.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/335.jpg?cfaea8',
    price:500
  }, {
    name:'Little Imp',
    description:'yellow',
    img:'http://cdnimg.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/334.jpg?cfaea8',
    price:3000
  }, {
    name:'Long Nose Monkey',
    decription:'grey',
    img:'http://cdnimg.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/492.jpg?cfaea8',
    price:5000
  }, {
    name:'Nicobar Bird',
    decription:'purple',
    img:'http://cdnimg.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/471.jpg?cfaea8',
    price: 6
  }, {
    name:'Slow Loris',
    decription: 'brown',
    img: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/49/09/8f/49098fbc3c9a37fb03034b45e89c5cd4.jpg',
    price:90
  }, {
    name:'Tucan',
    decription:'orange',
    img: 'http://cdnimg.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/526.jpg?cfaea8',
    price:100
  }, {
    name:'Fennec Fox'
    decription:'yellow'
    img:'http://cdnimg.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/526.jpg?cfaea8',
    price:500
  }, {
    name:'Sugar Glider',
    description: 'green',
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CNd03WIUwAAqKHg.jpg:large',
    price:1000000
  }
]

function animal() {
  // var animalName = ['Aye Aye', 

  var animalElement = document.getElementById("div0");

  for (i=0; i<animalName.length; i++) {
    animalElement.innerHTML += '<h2>' + animalName[i]+'</h2>' +'<p>' + animalDescription[i] +'</p>' + '<p>' + animalPrice[i] +'</p>' + '<p>' + animalImage[i] + '</p>';
  };
};

animal();
```

Comment: Your data is a set of similar objects, which means an array is the obvious structure in which to keep it. Why do you want to change that to an object? It's not clear exactly what you're asking for or what problem you have doing it. And *please*, [indent your code nicely](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-beautify/).

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution based off of what you currently have:

```
function generateAnimals() {
    var animalElements = document.getElementById("div0");
    var html = '';

    for (i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        var animal = animals[i];

        html += '<h2>' + animal.name + '</h2>' 
            + '<p>' + animal.description + '</p>'
            + '<p>' + animal.price + '</p>'
            + '<p>' + animal.image + '</p>';
    }

    animalElements.innerHTML += html;
}

generateAnimals();
```

Just be warned that creating elements like this can get messy once things start to become more complex.

Comment: @DonavanM calling innerHTML inside a loop causes multiple dom redraw. You might want to save the results in a var and do .innerHTML after the loop, only once.

Comment: You're right. I was simply showing a solution that didn't require much code change, but I think it's worth changing it to a single innerHTML call. Good catch. Going to change it now.

Comment: Your code will generate invalid HTML, and may be even open to injection depending on how the data is sourced.  Do not concatenate text data into an HTML context.

Comment: I see the typo now, thanks. I don't recommend creating HTML elements this way, either. Was just trying to help @Garrett Vangilder figure out how to get his function to work with his updated data structure. I'm not sure if he would have found it very helpful of me to tell him to "use [insert framework]" in response to the question.

Comment: @DonovanM You don't need to use a framework to set the text of an element.